# Reading Streamreader Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to read data directly from Share point excel,
Below is my API code

API Get method call:

```
public string Get()
    {
        string url =            
        "https://globalfunctionsshare.nam.citi.net/sites/otdrrm/_layouts/15/WopiFrame2.aspx?sourcedoc=/sites/otdrrm/Documents/tools/Legal%20Hold%20Application%20Tracker/Legal%20Hold%20Application%20Tracker%2020210702.xlsx&action=default";
        
        string value = GetRangeValue(url);

        return value;}

public string GetRangeValue(string url)
    {           
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
        //System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseValue = string.Empty;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string message = String.Format(
                    "GET failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);

                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            // Return the response.
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return responseValue;
        }
    }
```

OutPut:

[API Response Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4hQz.png)

I am getting the output as text obviously, but I need my result into DataTable so that I retrieve  the value that I need from DataTable.
Is there any possible way to achieve this?
Also I am not sure if this response is correct because i can't see any value from my excel.

Comment: Can you share the example of text you are getting? APIs usually do not return data table... you can create your own datatable from the response you are getting from api.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: i have added screenshot image, please check. Also i am not sure if the response is correct because i can't find any excel value in response that i am getting as text

Comment: What you are getting back is an HTML content... looks like some web form... is that expected? You can not convert that to datatable... I think you should learn more about the API you are calling to get the desired data at least in the form of JSON so that you can process it...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Oh! Please can you help me achieving this?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: My requirement is simple, we have an Excel on share point and i have to read a single value based on the ID that i'll pass a parameter. So for this i need to create an API basically a GET method

Comment: I have zero knowledge about Share point. You need to check if share point offers an API which can return data from excel based on the provided range.